# Concatenate multiple columns into new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume the folllowing table `users`

```
first_name   last_name   gender
-------------------------------
Britney      Spears      F
Mick         Jagger      M
Beyonce      Knowles     F
-------------------------------
```

I want to `concatenate` the values of this table and add them to a new colum called `total`, as follows:

```
first_name   last_name   gender   total
---------------------------------------------------
Britney      Spears      F        Britney Spears F
Mick         Jagger      M        Mick Jagger M
Beyonce      Knowles     F        Beyonce Knowles F
---------------------------------------------------
```

I have been trying multiple variations on:

```
select into [users] concat([first_name], [last_name], [gender]) as [total]
from   [users]
```

But this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why doesn't your code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a new column:

```
alter table add total varchar(max);  -- or whatever length

update users
    set total = concat([first_name], [last_name], [gender]);
```

Or better yet, add a computed column:

```
alter table add total as concat([first_name], [last_name], [gender]);
```